# What is the name of this connector / board?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable, breakout

I'm trying to make a custom HID, and would like to include a joystick, it has this carbon 6 wire ribbon cable, but I can't for the life of me find this kind of breakout board or even the connector name if I wanted to make a custom PCB, could anyone help me out?

[image: breakout board]
[image: connector]

Comment: FFC / FPC connector (FFC = Flat Flex Cable, FPC = Flexible Printed Circuits)

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/FPC-FFC-Flat-Flexible-Cable-Adapter-Board-Connectors-0-5mm-1-0mm-to-DIP-2-54mm/263768868111?hash=item3d69d9850f:m:matuGI3lDJ99qy1YY31Wazg

Comment: Resolder that black wire while you’re at it. It’s too close to the connector and it short something if you allow too much mechanical movement.